# UnicodeDecodeError: can't install PyAutoGUI using pip install

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, xlib, kde-plasma

I tried to install xlib-related module like PyAutoGUI I can't be able to install it.

After hiting `pip install PyAutoGUI` on terminal this message appears:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 0: invalid start byte

It's the same message that terminal shows me when trying to execute a script that use PyUserInput (another module that use xlib).

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by downgrading Python-Xlib package.

See issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-xlib/+bug/1522107).

For downgrade this module I ran on Terminal this line:

```
apt-get install python-xlib=0.14+20091101-1ubuntu2
```